# Preventing Additional Touches in Webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html, web-applications

I'm having a problem with the swipe code on my webapp.  Using a single finger, the swiping between pages works flawlessly, however, when I touch with a second finger and move it at the same time as the first, the app becomes confused about which finger to listen to.  This  generally causes things to go very wrong.  How can I go about ensuring that the only touch events the app respects are those triggered by the first finger touch?

The code for my swipe plugin looks like this:

```
(function($) {

        $.fn.movement = function(options) {


    var defaults = {
        threshold: { x: 150, y: 15 },
        mouseUp: function() {},
        mouseMove: function() { },
        mouseDown: function() { },
        scrollStart: function() { },
        scrollStop: function() { },
        scrollMove: function() { }
    };



    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    if (!this) return false;


    //alert(this.attr("id"));
    return this.each(function() {

        var me = $(this)

        // Private variables for each element
        var originalCoord = { x: 0, y: 0 }
        var lastCoord = {x: 0, y: 0 }
        var finalCoord = { x: 0, y: 0 }
        var velocity = { x: 0, y: 0 }
       function touchMove(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX // Updated X,Y coordinates
                finalCoord.y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY
                defaults.scrollMove(finalCoord);
                defaults.mouseMove(finalCoord,activeDirection());
        }

        function touchEnd(event) {
            var direction = stoppedDirection();
            defaults.scrollStop(finalCoord);
            defaults.mouseUp(velocity,direction);           
        }

        function touchStart(event) {
            originalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
            originalCoord.y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY
            lastCoord.x = originalCoord.x
            lastCoord.y = originalCoord.y
            finalCoord.x = originalCoord.x
            finalCoord.y = originalCoord.y
            defaults.scrollStart(originalCoord);
        }
        function activeDirection() {
            var direction = [];
            var vx = lastCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
            var vy = lastCoord.y - finalCoord.y;
            if (vy < 0 && (Math.abs(vy) > defaults.threshold.y))
                direction.push('down');
            else if (vy > 0 && (Math.abs(vy) > defaults.threshold.y))
                direction.push('up');
            if (vx < 0 && (Math.abs(vx) > defaults.threshold.x))
                direction.push('right');
            else if (vx > 0 && (Math.abs(vx) > defaults.threshold.x))
                direction.push('left');
            return direction;
        }

        function stoppedDirection() {
            var direction = [];
            velocity.x = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
            velocity.y = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y;
            if (velocity.y < 0 && (Math.abs(velocity.y) > defaults.threshold.y))
                direction.push('down');
            else if (velocity.y > 0 && (Math.abs(velocity.y) > defaults.threshold.y))
                direction.push('up');
            if (velocity.x < 0 && (Math.abs(velocity.x) > defaults.threshold.x))
                direction.push('right');
            else if (velocity.x > 0 && (Math.abs(velocity.x) > defaults.threshold.x))
                direction.push('left');
            return direction;
        }
        this.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
        this.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
        this.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchCancel, false);
       });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

For having better control on the Touch Events, jQuery Mobile can be a good option.

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I'd prefer to fix this within the existing plugin but its good to know there are alternatives if no practical solution exists for the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Each finger triggers its own touch events. So:

```
// put first finger down
touchstart,
// move that finger
touchmove, touchmove, touchmove, ...
// put second finger down
touchstart,
// move both fingers
touchmove, touchmove, touchmove, ...
// lift either finger
touchend,
// lift last finger
touchend.
```

I guess you start to get the idea of how to track the first finger now. The question would be: When two fingers are moving, how to tell which `touchmove` is which finger? The answer is the `identifier` property under a `Touch` object (the object you use for getting `pageX` and `pageY`).

So when the first finger down, record it's `identifier`. For upcoming touch events, iterate through `targetTouches` (or just `changeTouches`) and find the `Touch` object with the same `identifier`. If such `Touch` object doesn't exist in `changeTouches`, we do nothing. We don't care about other `Touch` objects.

In the end, you need to think about how you would like to handle the first finger's up. When the first finger is lifted while there are other fingers on the screen, does the second finger take over the first finger's power to scroll? Do we need to lift all fingers off the screen in order to reset the first finger's power? It's up to you.